# What kind of succulent is this?

Tags: identification, succulents

I found this while looking for some climbing succulents. I desperately want to know what kind of succulent it is.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that this looks to be the Graptopetalum Paraguayense variety of [Ghost Plant](http://gardeningsolutions.ifas.ufl.edu/plants/ornamentals/ghost-plant.html).

The rosettes are made up of clumps of leaves covered with a delicate coating called prunoise. It's gray if kept in part-shade, and will turn pink in bright sun, which is what it prefers, for at least a good part of the day. While hardy to about 10° Fahrenheit, it can also be grown as a houseplant. Keep it near a south, east, or west window in order to provide enough sun.

As with most succulents, it tolerates draught and likes well-draining, rocky soil. Over-watering can damage the roots and cause the leaves to fall prematurely, so make sure to let it almost fully dry out between waterings.

As you can see, it's quite striking in a container, but it's also very pretty in a rock garden, where it spreads out like a groundcover, or cascades over a wall.

It self-propagates by dropping leaves, which root themselves in the soil. You can also grow your own babies easily, by letting a fallen leaf dry out a bit until it hardens at the point where it broke off, and planting it wherever you'd like!

Answer (score 3):

That is gorgeous! I believe the plant is Ghost Plant (Graptopetalum Paraguayense). The color of the plant will change, depending on its growing conditions and it is hardy to zone 7b.